# calculating big O notation

Tags: c++, big-o

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    for (j=i; j<n/4; j++)
        sum++;
```

What is the big O for the above code?
I calculated the big O but I'm not sure if it's correct.

This is my answer

the outer loop will run `n/2` times

the inner loop will run `(n/4 - 1) = ((n-4)/4 )`

```
T(n) = (n/2) * ((n-4)/4 )
     = (n^2 -4n + 16)/8
     = 1/8 n^2 - 1/2 n +2
```

so the big O is `O(n^2)` is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in big O computations leading coefficients and subleading terms are dropped.

The [**formal definition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is that `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` if `f(x) <= M g(x)` for `x` beyond some `x0` and some constant `M`. In this case, `M = 1/8` and `x0 = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way of checking the big O of simple for loops that are nested within one another is this: `O(n ^ (number of loops))`

Note that the above technique is valid only if all the limits of the loop are real multiple of n.

In your question the inner loop is n/2 and outer loop is n/4. Both are real multiples of n. So the big O will be:   `O(n ^ 2)`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is O(n^2) and if that's all you care(normally that should be) then you are right. But I don't think the constant is 1/8 though.

If you want to be precise I think it should be:

```
n/4 + n/4 -1 + n/4 - 2 + ... 3 + 2 + 1 = n/4 *(n/4 + 1)/2 = n^2/32 + n/8
```

When i is larger than or equal to n/4, the inner loop wouldn't run. So you shouldn't count that part in.

Answer (score 1):

The formal steps, using Sigma Notation, are like the following:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how you come to the substitution for the inner sum (j from i to n/4). In my opinion the substitute should be: `floor(n/4 - i)`. You result also seems wrong (I would say Theta(n^2)).

Comment: Rectified! Thank you @Nobody.